# Subset GPS locations each x hours

Tags: r

I'm trying to do some cleaning in this GPS location data.frame

```
 $ ID         : Factor w/ 33 levels "I1","I10","I12",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
 $ Date.time  : POSIXlt, format: "2005-09-13 07:55:00" "2005-09-13 19:57:00" "2005-09-14 07:57:00" "2005-09-14 19:55:00" ...
 $ Latitude   : chr  "-27.4637" "-27.4637" "-27.46943333" "-27.46943" ...
 $ Longitude  : chr  "31.32513" "31.32513333" "31.33183333" "31.33183" ...
 $ Difflat    : num  0 0.0057 0 0.0158 0.0095 ...
 $ Difflong   : num  0 0.0067 0 0.0185 0.005 ...
```

Unfortunetaly, my GPS locations were not always taken at the same interval of time for each ID. Even one ID can have different interval of time.

For example, I1 can have a location each 4h and I5 each 8h and 12h. There is also "bug" that the GPS locations might be each 4h -> 16:00/20:00/00:00 and then it switched to 06:00/10:00... so there is a gap of 6 hours during the switch.

So, I would like to uniformize my dataset to have a location each 12 hours for example. Because I have ID that have a location each day instead or each 8 hours, it will be nice if I could apply a different subset to each ID.

I searched in lubridate, zoo, xts, but I didn't find anything that help me. I'm new to cleaning data with R so the solution might be easy and just under my eyes.

Here is the first line of my dataframe.

```
ID           Date.time     Latitude   Longitude Difflat Difflong
 I1 2005-09-13 07:55:00     -27.4637    31.32513  0.0000   0.0000
 I1 2005-09-13 19:57:00     -27.4637 31.32513333  0.0057   0.0067
 I1 2005-09-14 07:57:00 -27.46943333 31.33183333  0.0000   0.0000
 I1 2005-09-14 19:55:00    -27.46943    31.33183  0.0158   0.0185
 I1 2005-09-15 04:48:00     -27.4536 31.35031667  0.0095   0.0050
 I1 2005-09-15 16:49:00    -27.44415 31.34536667  0.0259   0.0372
```

Also, I have another question.

Sometimes the GPS failed before it was removed of the animal. So it created a numbers of continuous rows in my dataframe that have the same GPS locations. I would like to remove those rows. As you can see in my dataframe, the columns Difflat and Difflong were created for this purpose

```
dataframe_complet$Difflat<- c(Latitude[2:nrow(Latitude),1] - Latitude[1:(nrow(Latitude)-1),1],NA)
```

I would use  this :

```
y<-subset(dataframe_complet, Difflat=="0" & Difflong=="0",)
```

But I don't want to just remove the rows that have a difference of 0 in Latitude and Longitude. I need to consider the time too. It's normal to have the same position if there is not a lot of time between the two locations. So, I would like to remove the difflat AND difflong < 0.0002 but for a period of time greater than 3 days. If the GPS locations is at the same place for more than 3 days, it's probably a problem with the GPS.

UPDATE
So,

1- How do you subset a date.time variable each 4-8-12 hours?

In this example, I would like to keep rows each 12 hours. To help me do that, I did a column (Difftime = Date.time row2 - Date.time row1). As you can see, I have already have a row each 12 hours for I2 but I want to eliminate the rows in between. That's the same time for the others. I want to be at 12 h intervals. Sometime, the interval pattern for one ID change. It can be each 12 h and then switch to each 8 hours.

```
ID           Date.time     Latitude     Difftime 
 I2 2006-02-02 04:45:00     -27.4265 -12.000000  
 I2 2006-02-02 09:31:00     -27.4265  -4.766667  
 I2 2006-02-02 16:44:00 -27.42498333  -7.200000  
 I2 2006-02-03 04:45:00 -27.43096667 -12.000000  
 I1 2005-10-23 15:46:00    -27.51735 -10.000000  
 I1 2005-10-23 17:46:00    -27.51735  -2.000000  
 I1 2005-10-24 03:46:00 -27.52548333 -10.000000  
 I1 2005-10-24 05:46:00    -27.52548  -2.000000  
I17 2010-06-03 20:43:00     -27.5083   -8.0000000  
I17 2010-06-04 00:43:00     -27.5086   -4.0000000  
I17 2010-06-04 04:43:00 -27.50951667   -4.0000000  
I17 2010-06-04 08:43:00 -27.50961667   -4.0000000
```

So, I would like to have something like that :

```
     ID           Date.time     Latitude     Difftime 
     I2 2006-02-02 04:45:00     -27.4265 -12.000000 
     I2 2006-02-02 16:44:00 -27.42498333  -12.00000
     I2 2006-02-03 04:45:00 -27.43096667 -12.000000  
     I1 2005-10-23 15:46:00    -27.51735 -12.000000   
     I1 2005-10-24 03:46:00 -27.52548333 -12.000000   
    I17 2010-06-03 20:43:00     -27.5083   -8.0000000    
    I17 2010-06-04 08:43:00 -27.50961667   -4.0000000
```

2- How do you remove GPS locations that stay at the same place by considering the time variable?

In this first example below, I want to eliminate row 1599 until the end because the GPS locations stay the same for a long period of time (for example more than 3 days) as you can easily see with columns Difflat and Difflong.

```
     ID           Date.time     Latitude   Longitude Difflat Difflong
1589 I15 2011-01-31 18:06:00 -27.40186667 31.34063333  0.0015   0.0077
1590 I15 2011-01-31 22:06:00 -27.40338333 31.33293333  0.0002   0.0025
1591 I15 2011-02-01 02:07:00 -27.40318333    31.33045  0.0005   0.0002
1593 I15 2011-02-01 10:06:00 -27.40543333     31.3367  0.0003   0.0006
1595 I15 2011-02-01 18:07:00 -27.40863333     31.3318  0.0070   0.0036
1596 I15 2011-02-01 22:07:00 -27.40163333 31.32823333  0.0023   0.0148
1599 I15 2011-02-02 10:07:00     -27.4039 31.34306667  0.0000   0.0000
1600 I15 2011-12-08 06:40:00     -27.4039 31.34306667  0.0021   0.0012
1604 I15 2011-12-09 10:05:00 -27.40603333 31.34426667  0.0000   0.0001
1606 I15 2011-12-09 18:05:00 -27.40606667 31.34426667  0.0000   0.0001
1607 I15 2011-12-09 22:05:00 -27.40606667 31.34433333  0.0001   0.0001
1609 I15 2011-12-10 06:05:00 -27.40608333 31.34426667  0.0000   0.0001
1612 I15 2011-12-10 18:05:00      -27.406 31.34433333  0.0001   0.0002
1614 I15 2011-12-11 02:05:00    -27.40605 31.34421667  0.0000   0.0000
1616 I15 2011-12-11 10:05:00 -27.40603333 31.34428333  0.0001   0.0001
1618 I15 2011-12-11 18:05:00 -27.40606667 31.34423333  0.0000   0.0000
1621 I15 2011-12-12 06:04:00      -27.406 31.34431667  0.0000   0.0001
1623 I15 2011-12-12 14:05:00 -27.40601667 31.34431667  0.0000   0.0001
```

It happened sometime that there is a difference of 0 (Difflat,Difflong) between 2 rows or so. Those rows, I don't want to eliminate them. For example :

```
 ID           Date.time     Latitude   Longitude Difflat Difflong
I15 2010-08-09 12:34:00 -27.52586667 31.17358333  0.0039   0.0019
I15 2010-08-09 16:34:00    -27.52975 31.17546667  0.0049   0.0007
I15 2010-08-09 20:35:00 -27.53463333 31.17473333  0.0000   0.0000
I15 2010-08-10 00:34:00 -27.53468333     31.1747  0.0006   0.0013
```

So I want to eliminate rows that stays Difflat AND Difflong < 0.0002 for more than 3 days (number of rows differ from an ID to the other depends on the interval of time used (GPS location each 4-6-8 hours).

I hope I give enough details and they are clear.

Thank you for your response!!

Comment: Can you add a small data example with multiple ID and the desired result?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I was on the field. See above, I edited my question. Hope it helps! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to do that with `dplyr` and `RcppRoll`.

Regarding part 1, you'll want to create a cumulative sum on the Difftime object. Then `filter` out the rows that have a modulo of 12 different than 0. This works with your example. Make sure that with your real life example, the first data or each ID is a good one (one that is part of the 12h ones).

```
library(dplyr)
df1%>%
  group_by(ID)%>%
  mutate(Difftime=as.numeric(difftime(Date.time,lag(Date.time))),
         Difftime=ifelse(is.na(Difftime),0,Difftime),
         Difftime_cumsum=round(cumsum(Difftime)))%>%
  filter(Difftime_cumsum %% 12 ==0)

     ID           Date.time  Latitude  Difftime Difftime_cumsum
  <chr>              <dttm>     <dbl>     <dbl>           <dbl>
1    I2 2006-02-02 04:45:00 -27.42650  0.000000               0
2    I2 2006-02-02 16:44:00 -27.42498  7.216667              12
3    I2 2006-02-03 04:45:00 -27.43097 12.016667              24
4    I1 2005-10-23 15:46:00 -27.51735  0.000000               0
5    I1 2005-10-24 03:46:00 -27.52548 10.000000              12
6   I17 2010-06-03 20:43:00 -27.50830  0.000000               0
7   I17 2010-06-04 08:43:00 -27.50962  4.000000              12
```

**data1**

```
    df1 <- read.table(text="ID           Date.time     Latitude     Difftime 
    I2 '2006-02-02 04:45:00'     -27.4265 -12.000000  
    I2 '2006-02-02 09:31:00'     -27.4265  -4.766667  
    I2 '2006-02-02 16:44:00' -27.42498333  -7.200000  
    I2 '2006-02-03 04:45:00' -27.43096667 -12.000000  
    I1 '2005-10-23 15:46:00'    -27.51735 -10.000000  
    I1 '2005-10-23 17:46:00'    -27.51735  -2.000000  
    I1 '2005-10-24 03:46:00' -27.52548333 -10.000000  
    I1 '2005-10-24 05:46:00'    -27.52548  -2.000000  
    I17 '2010-06-03 20:43:00'     -27.5083   -8.0000000  
    I17 '2010-06-04 00:43:00'     -27.5086   -4.0000000  
    I17 '2010-06-04 04:43:00' -27.50951667   -4.0000000  
    I17 '2010-06-04 08:43:00' -27.50961667   -4.0000000",
     header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
    df1$Date.time <- as.POSIXct(df1$Date.time)
```

For your second question, basically, you `summarise` your lat and long data by day, apply a 3-day moving average using `roll_meanl` and filter the lines where `cumsum` is smaller than 0.0002. You then `semi_join` on ID and dates to get your initial lines back.

```
df2%>%
  group_by(ID,date)%>%
  summarise(dailymean_difflat=round(mean(Difflat,na.rm=TRUE),4),
            dailymean_difflong=round(mean(Difflong,na.rm=TRUE),4))%>%
  mutate(roll_mean_lat=round(roll_meanl(dailymean_difflat,3),4),
         roll_mean_long=round(roll_meanl(dailymean_difflong,3),4),
         cut=ifelse(!is.na(roll_mean_lat)& !is.na(roll_mean_long) &
                    roll_mean_lat<0.0002 & roll_mean_long<0.0002,1,0))%>%
  filter(cumsum(cut)<1)%>%
  semi_join(df2,.)

   row  ID           Date.time  Latitude Longitude Difflat Difflong       date
1 1589 I15 2011-01-31 18:06:00 -27.40187  31.34063  0.0015   0.0077 2011-01-31
2 1590 I15 2011-01-31 22:06:00 -27.40338  31.33293  0.0002   0.0025 2011-02-01
3 1591 I15 2011-02-01 02:07:00 -27.40318  31.33045  0.0005   0.0002 2011-02-01
4 1593 I15 2011-02-01 10:06:00 -27.40543  31.33670  0.0003   0.0006 2011-02-01
5 1595 I15 2011-02-01 18:07:00 -27.40863  31.33180  0.0070   0.0036 2011-02-01
6 1596 I15 2011-02-01 22:07:00 -27.40163  31.32823  0.0023   0.0148 2011-02-02
7 1599 I15 2011-02-02 10:07:00 -27.40390  31.34307  0.0000   0.0000 2011-02-02
8 1600 I15 2011-12-08 06:40:00 -27.40390  31.34307  0.0021   0.0012 2011-12-08
```

**data2**

```
df2 <- read.table(text="row     ID           Date.time     Latitude   Longitude Difflat Difflong
1589 I15 '2011-01-31 18:06:00' -27.40186667 31.34063333  0.0015   0.0077
1590 I15 '2011-01-31 22:06:00' -27.40338333 31.33293333  0.0002   0.0025
1591 I15 '2011-02-01 02:07:00' -27.40318333    31.33045  0.0005   0.0002
1593 I15 '2011-02-01 10:06:00' -27.40543333     31.3367  0.0003   0.0006
1595 I15 '2011-02-01 18:07:00' -27.40863333     31.3318  0.0070   0.0036
1596 I15 '2011-02-01 22:07:00' -27.40163333 31.32823333  0.0023   0.0148
1599 I15 '2011-02-02 10:07:00'     -27.4039 31.34306667  0.0000   0.0000
1600 I15 '2011-12-08 06:40:00'     -27.4039 31.34306667  0.0021   0.0012
1604 I15 '2011-12-09 10:05:00' -27.40603333 31.34426667  0.0000   0.0001
1606 I15 '2011-12-09 18:05:00' -27.40606667 31.34426667  0.0000   0.0001
1607 I15 '2011-12-09 22:05:00' -27.40606667 31.34433333  0.0001   0.0001
1609 I15 '2011-12-10 06:05:00' -27.40608333 31.34426667  0.0000   0.0001
1612 I15 '2011-12-10 18:05:00'      -27.406 31.34433333  0.0001   0.0002
1614 I15 '2011-12-11 02:05:00'    -27.40605 31.34421667  0.0000   0.0000
1616 I15 '2011-12-11 10:05:00' -27.40603333 31.34428333  0.0001   0.0001
1618 I15 '2011-12-11 18:05:00' -27.40606667 31.34423333  0.0000   0.0000
1621 I15 '2011-12-12 06:04:00'      -27.406 31.34431667  0.0000   0.0001
1623 I15 '2011-12-12 14:05:00' -27.40601667 31.34431667  0.0000   0.0001",header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
df2$Date.time <- as.POSIXct(df2$Date.time)
df2$date <- as.Date(df2$Date.time)
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your reply. I'll have a better look at that this week or next week. It look good thought!

Comment: I suspect that you real life data is different from the example you gave. FOr example, you might have a "wrong" 4h reading at the beginning. This will cause problems. Have you thought about simply doing the average location per AM and PM period?

Comment: Sorry, I was writing down my interogations before posting. Here is what I can see:
Part 1 :  I had to add Difftime_cumsum >=11.5 because sometime there was a difference of few minutes between two intervals of 12 h.
Also, how do you assign the result of filter to an object?  I try too, but when I do so, it’s says it doesn’t find the  object Difftime_cumsum .

Comment: To assign the whole pipe to an object, the first line in the example should be: `new_object <- df1%>%`

Comment: Part 2 : I got this error message:
Error in filter_impl(.data, quo) : 
  Evaluation error: cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'double'.
Also, sometimes, I can have 13-17 of April and then 2 of May. If there is a bug with the GPS in April and not in May and we do a mean between 16-17 of April and 2 of May, because of the 2 of May, we will not be able to eliminate 16-17 of April.  
 If I have a GPS that stop working and then “go back on track” again, because it’s cumulative sum, the object “cut” will be > 1. So we will remove rows that we have to keep.

Comment: Thanks for the object assignation, I'll try it !